# Как поставить 6 блоков в 2 ровные колонки?

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox

В каждом блоке сверху небольшая иконка и снизу текст. Внутри блока они должны выровняться по-центру и каждый блок должен быть одного размера.

```css
.icons {
  font-family: RobotoRegular;
  font-size: 18pt;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons div div {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1px;
}

.icons div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div>
    <div class="icon1">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
      <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
      <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon3">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
      <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="icon4">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
      <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
      <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon6">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
      <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.icons div div {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```css
.icons {
  font-family: RobotoRegular;
  font-size: 18pt;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons div div {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.icons div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div>
    <div class="icon1">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
      <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
      <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon3">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
      <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="icon4">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
      <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
      <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon6">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
      <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, только как внутри блока выровнять иконку и текст?

Comment: @Rimafi, для каждого icon'а задай display: flex и выравнивай